# Why only embedded font can be rotated in actionscript?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, embedded-fonts, text-rotation

You can rotate embedded font but can not rotate device font.
Why adobe allows only embedded font to be rotated?
Are there technical problems to rotate device font?

Comment: Yes, there are "technical problems", or at least, text is handled in completely different ways when the font is embedded as opposed to using device fonts. Embedding the font basically means that the characters in the font is converted to Flash vector graphics at compile time, so it can be handled like any other vector graphics by the Flash Player, while device fonts are more like text in for example HTML. Somewhat simplified, but this is at least the basis of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the blendMode to "layer" on the text.  I know that allows you to scale it--you may also find it will let you rotate it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But `text.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER` did not allow text to rotate(`text.rotation`). 
And `text.scaleY` worked regardless of `BlendMode.LAYER`.